# Unclear about how repeatable-read works in RDBMS

Tags: mysql, isolation-level, phantom-read

I'm uncertain about how repeatable-read operates in RDBMS. I initially thought it functions similarly to Git branching, where an exact copy of the current database is utilized. However, I'm puzzled by the following scenario:

```
Tx1                                       Tx2
1. BEGIN;                                 1. BEGIN;
2. SELECT * FROM TABLE; (10 ROWS)         2. SELECT * FROM TABLE; (10 ROWS)

3. INSERT NEW ROW IN TABLE;
4. COMMIT;

                                          3. UPDATE ROW WITH ID=11; (executes successfully)
```

When Tx1 and Tx2 are operating with independent snapshots, how can Tx2 access the newly created row by Tx1? I recognize this as an instance of phantom reads but am unclear about why it occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You might mistaken phantom reads with non-repeatable reads and your example is specific to MySQL.

[REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_repeatable_read)

> ... It prevents any rows that are queried from being changed by other transactions, thus blocking non-repeatable reads but not phantom reads ...

That phantom read you are getting is because you are inserting a new row, hence in doesn't modify any data that `Tx2` was reading in the first place. This case is documented (see link above) and allowing phantom reads!
This is common for RDBMS to allow phantom reads on `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level. However different RDBMS defines it differently.

This is handy reference that is possible and what not per isolation level:

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Nonrepeatable Read | Phantom Read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Read uncommitted** | Possible | Possible | Possible |
| **Read committed** | Not possible | Possible | Possible |
| **Repeatable read** | Not possible | Not possible | Possible |
| **Serializable** | Not possible | Not possible | Not possible |

This is what MySQL documentation is saying about [phantom rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html)

> `SELECT * FROM child WHERE id > 100 FOR UPDATE;`
> The query scans the index starting from the first record where id is
> bigger than 100. Let the table contain rows having id values of 90 and
> 102. If the locks set on the index records in the scanned range do not lock out inserts made in the gaps (in this case, the gap between 90
> and 102), another session can insert a new row into the table with an
> id of 101. If you were to execute the same SELECT within the same
> transaction, you would see a new row with an id of 101 (a “phantom”)
> in the result set returned by the query.

As you can see it doesn't specify if gap is also from 103 to MAX_INT.
Trying execute in a lock mode, you will see phantom rows.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE FOR UPDATE; (11 ROWS)
SELECT * FROM TABLE FOR SHARE; (11 ROWS)
```

This is why your `UPDATE` was successful.

Interestingly enough if you run regular non locking `SELECT` after locking one, phantom rows will disappear.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE; (10 ROWS)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not answer the question of why phantom read occurs by making a newly inserted row visible in T1 after an update as it talks about locking reads and locks, while the example in the question uses non-locking reads. Locking reads and non-locking reads can produce different results within the same transaction as locking statements always affect the last committed version of the row, regardless of the initial snapshot established by a non-locking read! Read Bill Karwin's excellent answer to the duplicate question explaining why innodb behaves the way it does.

Comment: In did, looks like a good answer. But why it falls back to Read committed then

Comment: That's how MVCC is umplemented in innodb.

Comment: @SerhiiH The crux of my concern is why the insertion appeared. Consider a scenario where we have 10 rows in the table and two transactions, T1 and T2, running concurrently. Both T1 and T2 utilize separate snapshots of the table. If T1 modifies any row, the alterations are not visible to T2. This is because T1 executed the update on its own snapshot. In cases where updates on existing rows are not visible, why are insert operations visible?

Comment: It's visible from statements using locks because Repeatable read doesn't apply to them and they always affecting last committed data, so Read committed is applied instead. Statements such as locking SELECTs, UPDATE, DELETE.  In MySQL you just can't have Repeatable read with them even if you explicitly set it. Workaround is use Serializable

Comment: @SerhiiH I see. That answers my question. Thanks a lot.